# Out of memory issue Bitmap

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, bitmapimage, mediastore

getting out of memory issue

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
                final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
                Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                        null, orderBy);
                int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                count = imagecursor.getCount();
                thumbnails = new Bitmap[count];
                arrPath = new String[count];
                thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                    arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                }
                GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
                imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                imagecursor.close();
```

getting Out of memory error here on bitmap:

```
Bitmap   thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

it crashing in some devices
Please help

Comment: Logcat please and also what is the size of thumbnails[] when it does crash?

Comment: @MorrisonChang as i said it crashing in some devices, currently i don't have that device to reproduce this issue.

Comment: how many Bitmaps are you creating there?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Out of memory at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Android training manuals, there are a few documents telling you how to do this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Personally, I would use [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compress the bitmap image using the `compress` method from the Android bitmap class.  I ran into this issue a while back and ended up having to compress the images I was using..

Check out the description of the `compress` method at the link below.  It should be fairly straightforward.  You just choose your format from the enum's, the "quality", and the output stream.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: I really don't have time to fire up Eclipse and find a line of code I wrote 3 years ago.  Just use the reference above and Google around for an example.  This is another example using `BitmapFactory.Options`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966